# static keyword before @protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, static, protocols

It is possible to write the code like this:

```
static @protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>    
...    
@end
```

And it is successfully compiled.
Why there is no error? How is **static** interpreted by compiler?

Comment: logically it makes no sense to make a protocol 'static' explicitly, as they are already a kinda 'static' interface declarations on abstract level anyway (but I would use carefully the word 'static' here as it matches the C keyword as well).

Comment: Ok, but why there is no error? Compiler just doesn't know what to do with it? Or what?

Comment: I'm not sure what kinda error do you expect actually? and for what? the protocols are already 'static' interface declarations, you cannot make them 'double-static' or 'no-static'; so if you write the `static` (or `const`, `inline`, `volatile` etc...) keyword explicitly in your code like this (logically none of them makes sense as the protocols are not runtime objects), __you literally make no difference logically__ – so there is no reason of any error would be generated in such situation, but you can interpret that as the compiler does not bother and gracefully ignores those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's obviously being silently ignored as you cannot specify the storage class of a protocol as it makes no sense.

Comment: @CHiP-love-NY Not really; no.  As I say, the compiler is simply ignoring the storage class specifier.